# jFuzzyLogic FCL editor doesn't work on Ubuntu Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jfuzzylogic

I'm working on a project with jFuzzyLogic and so I need to create rules with `.fcl` files.

Eclipse has a plugin for FCL editor with auto-completion and it works fine on Windows, but since I don't have any Windows on my machine I have installed it on Ubuntu 14.04LTE.

When I try to edit FCL file with Eclipse on Ubuntu I get this kind of error:

```
Unable to create editor ID net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.Fcl: The editor class could not be     instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class     name was mistyped in plugin.xml.
```

Here is an Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create injector for net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.Fcl
at net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.ui.internal.FclActivator.createInjector(FclActivator.java:71)
at net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.ui.internal.FclActivator.getInjector(FclActivator.java:55)
at net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.ui.FclExecutableExtensionFactory.getInjector(FclExecutableExtensionFactory.java:26)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.guice.AbstractGuiceAwareExecutableExtensionFactory.create(AbstractGuiceAwareExecutableExtensionFactory.java:49)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:262)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createPart(EditorManager.java:875)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:609)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:315)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2946)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2846)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2777)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(IDE.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:76)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.preferences.IPreferenceStoreInitializer annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=builderPreferenceInitializer) was bound.
at   net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.ui.AbstractFclUiModule.configureBuilderPreferenceStoreInitializer(AbstractFclUiModule.java:78)

2) No implementation for org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.preferences.IPreferenceStoreInitializer annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=RefactoringPreferences) was bound.
 at   net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.ui.AbstractFclUiModule.configureIPreferenceStoreInitializer(AbstractFclUiModule.java:143)

3) Could not find a suitable constructor in org.eclipse.xtext.ui.refactoring.impl.DefaultRenameStrategy. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
at     org.eclipse.xtext.ui.refactoring.impl.DefaultRenameStrategy.class(DefaultRenameStrategy.java:96)

at org.eclipse.xtext.service.MethodBasedModule.configure(MethodBasedModule.java:55)

3 errors
at   com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:354)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.initializeStatically(InjectorBuilder.java:152)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:105)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:92)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
at net.sf.jFuzzyLogic.ui.internal.FclActivator.createInjector(FclActivator.java:67)
... 72 more
```

And here is Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
```

Comment: Looks like a straightforward case of a bug in the plugin.

Comment: I've already submitted a bug report to the author, but I guess it didn't harm asking for possible solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody comes across the same bug, I solved it by installing Eclipse Luna manually (not from Ubuntu repositories) and then installing plugin from scratch. Worked fine.